# How to override encapsulated function (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, overriding

Hi I have jQuery based core code which I cannot touch. It contains a function e.g.:

```
Library.Plugin.init = function (param1, param2) {
    function doSomething(paramA, paramB, paramC) {
    }
};
```

Library & Plugin are just object containers.

I'd like to change some parts of doSomething() function while keeping the others working as they are. (I think it is called overriding)

How can I achieve it please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Open your favorite editor, find the `doSomething()` function, and just change it. As it's defined locally inside the `init` function, you can't just randomly change it programatically elsewhere in the code.

Comment: `function doSomething` is `private`it means you cant override it.
You will have to edit yourself the `function doSomething` in the plugin code itself

Comment: Thank you all for clarifying.

Is the `init` function special in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `doSomething` *per se*, but you could control its behaviour by arranging for it to branch, internally.

For example, a switch/case structure which depends on one (or more) of the function's paramters :

```
function doSomething(a, b, c) {
    switch (a) {
        case 0:
          ...
        break;
        case 1:
          ...
        break;
        case 2:
          ...
        break;
        default:
          ...
    }
}
```

Thus, `doSomething` would be controlled wholly by `Library.Plugin.init`.

You could similarly branch on the state of some outer object :

```
function doSomething(a, b, c) {
    switch (outerObject.state) {
        case 0:
          ...
        break;
        case 1:
          ...
        break;
        case 2:
          ...
        break;
        default:
          ...
    }
}
```

Here, `doSomething` would be determined by `Library.Plugin.init` with regard to the formal prams `a, b, c`, but also controlled by whatever other code had the power to change `outerObject.state`.

These are just examples. The range of possibilities is endless. You are limited chiefly by your imagination.